# How do you inline a color column with gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

Considering the accepted answer at [Gnuplot: Variable colors (and linewidths) for 2D-Vector plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914162/gnuplot-variable-colors-and-linewidths-for-2d-vector-plot), why doesn't this work?:

```
set xrange [0:10]
set yrange [0:10]
plot '-','-','-','-','-' with vectors lw 3 lc rgb variable
1
1
1
1 
e
1
2
3
4
e
2
2
2
2
e
0
0
0
0
e
0x000000
0xff0000
0xff0000
0xffff00
0x382288
e
```

Error: line 26: Not enough columns for variable color

line 26 is the first color 0x000000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for the following:

```
### inline data
reset session

set xrange [0:10]
set yrange [0:10]
plot '-' u 1:2:3:4:5 with vectors lw 3 lc rgb variable
1  1  2  0  0x000000
1  2  2  0  0xff0000
1  3  2  0  0xff0000
1  4  2  0  0xffff00
2  5  2  0  0x382288
e
### end of code
```

Personally, I would prefer the following way. It has the advantage that you can "re-use" the data in a further plot. Whereas with `'-'` you would have to enter the data again. Check `help special-filenames`.

```
### inline data with datablock
reset session

$Data <<EOD
1  1  2  0  0x000000
1  2  2  0  0xff0000
1  3  2  0  0xff0000
1  4  2  0  0xffff00
2  5  2  0  0x382288
EOD

set xrange [0:10]
set yrange [0:10]
plot $Data u 1:2:3:4:5 with vectors lw 3 lc rgb variable
### end of code
```

**Result:** (for both versions)

[image]